# get tweets for particular twitter object via latest twitter gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

How can I access tweets for a particular tweet object for ex: "@testtweets"?

I am using latest  twitter  gem and have applied following steps:

```
@client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  config.consumer_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  config.oauth_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  config.oauth_token_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
end

@client.search("to:@testtweets", :result_type => "recent").take(3)
```

The above returning an empty array. while I have few tweets for the object on twitter. I also tried object @sachin and it's returning few tweet objects.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the search syntax but that looks like it would return messages sent **to** `@testtweets`, rather than simply returning `@testtweets` tweets.  Is that what you require? Are the key, secret etc the ones for the `@testtweets` account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter search is not an exhaustive archive of public tweets.
You can use **user_timeline** method to get last 3 tweets of this user like :

```
client.user_timeline("@testtweets").take(3)
```

Edit -

A better solution, if you just want to get tweets where you are mentionned, is :

```
client.mentions_timeline
```

This works only for authenticated user

Comment: hey is there any finders methods on return array of user_timeline method. I need to get particular tweet by its id , I am not sure how to get it